# Raman model equations using RK4

Tags: ode, modeling

I am trying to solve below ODE equations for Raman model but I am having errors, mostly overflow in multiply and add. Please I need your help. Below is the code I have written so far. I am new to Python thought. Thanks

```python
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Solving Raman model equations using fourth order Runge Kutta methods
def RK4(Ps, Pp, Ns, Np):
    k1 = dz*funPs(Ps, Pp)
    k2 = dz*funPs(Ps+k1/2, Pp+k1/2)
    k3 = dz*funPs(Ps+k2/2, Pp+k2/2)
    k4 = dz*funPs(Ps+k3,Pp+k3)
    
    r1 = dz*funPp(Ps, Pp, Ns)
    r2 = dz*funPp(Ps+r1/2, Pp+r1/2, Ns+r1/2)
    r3 = dz*funPp(Ps+r2/2, Pp+r2/2, Ns+r2/2)
    r4 = dz*funPp(Ps+r3,Pp+r3, Ns+r3)
    
    q1 = dz*funNs(Ps, Pp, Ns, Np)
    q2 = dz*funNs(Ps+q1/2, Pp+q1/2, Ns+q1/2, Np+q1/2)
    q3 = dz*funNs(Ps+q2/2, Pp+q2/2, Ns+q2/2, Np+q2/2)
    q4 = dz*funNs(Ps+q3,Pp+q3, Ns+q3, Np+q3)
    
    v1 = dz*funNp(Ps, Pp, Np)
    v2 = dz*funNp(Ps+v1/2, Pp+v1/2, Np+v1/2)
    v3 = dz*funNp(Ps+v2/2, Pp+v2/2, Np+v2/2)
    v4 = dz*funNp(Ps+v3,Pp+v3, Np+v3)
    
    Ps = Ps + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 +k4)/6
    Pp = Pp + (r1 + 2*r2 + 2*r3 +r4)/6
    Ns = Ns + (q1 + 2*q2 + 2*q3 +q4)/6
    Np = Np + (v1 + 2*v2 + 2*v3 +v4)/6
    return Ps, Pp, Ns, Np


def funPs(Ps, Pp):
    a = -(alphaRS + alphaS)*Ps
    b = (gR/Aeff)*Ps*Pp
    return a + b

def funPp(Ps, Pp, Ns):
    a = -(alphaRP + alphaP)*Pp
    b = -(wS/wP)*(gR/Aeff)*(Ps*Ns + (h*wS/2)*B0)*Pp
    return a + b

def funNs(Ps, Pp, Ns, Np):
    a = (-alphaRS - alphaS + (gR/Aeff)*Pp)*Ns
    b = (gR/Aeff)*(np.sqrt(2*Pp*Np))*Ps
    c = (alphaRS + alphaS + (gR/Aeff)*Pp)*(h*wS/2)*B0
    return a + b + c

def funNp(Ps, Pp, Np):
    a = -(alphaRP + alphaP)*Np
    b = -(wS/wP)*(gR/Aeff)*(Ps)*np.sqrt(2*Pp*Np)
    c = (alphaRP + alphaP)*(h*wS/2)*B0
    d = (wS/wP)*(gR/Aeff)*(Ps)*(2*Pp*np.sqrt(h*wS/2)*B0)
    return a + b + c + d

# calculate raman susceptibility
def chi_r_s(w):
    m = (raman_real + 1j*raman_imag)
    return m

def chi_r_i(w):
    n = (raman_real + 1j*raman_imag)
    return n[::-1]

pump = [1550]
for i in range(len(pump)):
 raman_freq = open('Raman frequency.txt')
 raman_real = open('Raman real part.txt')
 raman_imag = open('Raman imag part.txt')
 #d_lamda = open('lamda.txt')
 raman_freq = raman_freq.readlines()
 raman_real = raman_real.readlines()
 raman_imag = raman_imag.readlines()
 #d_lamda = d_lamda.readlines()
 raman_freq = np.array(list(map(float, raman_freq)))
 raman_real = np.array(list(map(float, raman_real)))
 raman_imag = np.array(list(map(float, raman_imag)))
 #d_lamda = np.array(list(map(float, d_lamda)))
 raman_freq = np.array(raman_freq)/(10**12)
 #b_x = np.zeros(5000) 
 #b_y = np.zeros(5000)
 d_lamda = np.zeros(5000)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 gR = 0.0096 #w-1/m-1 # nonlinear coefficient 
 dz = 1  # m  # step size of fibre
 c = 299792458  #speed of light(m/s) 
 nz = 5000 # number of steps
 fibre_length = nz*dz # 25 m 
 alphaRS = 4e-3
 alphaS = 4.61e-3 # signal attenuation coefficient
 alphaRP = 4e-3
 alphaP = 6.9e-3     # pump attenuation coefficient
 pumpzero = 1550 # nm  pump wavelength 
 Frepump = 193.1e12    # Ghz
 Freqsignal = 181.6e12
 wP = 2*math.pi*Frepump
 wS = 2*math.pi*raman_freq + wP  #rad/ps
 Aeff = 72.2e-6
 h = 6.62e-34
 B0 = 10e12
  
 
 #Set inial values for pump, signal and noise power
 Ps = 0.1    # in W
 Pp = 0.3162 # in W
 Ns = 1e-4   # in W
 Np = 0.0032 # in W
 z = 0       # propagated length

 for j in range(int(nz)):
    Ps, Pp, Ns, Np = RK4(Ps, Pp, Ns, Np)
    z+=dz
 
 lamda = c/(wS/2/math.pi*1e3 + c/pumpzero)
 #plt.xlim(1551.4,1700)
 #plt.ylim(0,11.5)
 x = round(pump[i] - pumpzero,2)
 x = str(x)
```

Comment: `dz=1` seems suspect. The stability of the method depends on having a small enough time step. Unless you really need a custom time-stepping routine, just use an existing library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing the method you should have gotten doubts:

- k1,k2,... updates Ps
- r1,r2,... updates Pp
- q1,q2,... updates Ns
- v1,v2,... updates Np

This is realized in your code in the naming of the derivative functions and the final assemblage of the component updates.

Thus a line like

```
    r2 = dz*funPp(Ps+r1/2, Pp+r1/2, Ns+r1/2)
```

is semantically wrong, apples and oranges. It should be

```
    r2 = dz*funPp(Ps+k1/2, Pp+r1/2, Ns+q1/2)
```

Now the logistical problem is that `q1` is not computed at this stage. This can be easily solve by reordering the lines of the computation, so that `k1,r1,q1,v1` are computed first, then `k2,r2,q2,v2` etc.

An implementation using vectors and vector-valued functions is explained in [Runge-Kutta 4th order with 4 ODEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405185/is-there-a-better-way-to-tidy-this-chuck-of-code-it-is-the-runge-kutta-4th-orde) or in [Energy conservation in RK4 integration scheme in C++](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42178/energy-conservation-in-rk4-integration-scheme-in-c) for a mechanical second order system. The advantage is the use of less code lines for the method and more flexibility if the state vector dimension changes.

Comment: Hi Lutz, thank you for this response, does this mean I will update only k2, r2, q2 and v2 or all of the parameters.

Comment: Hi Lutz, I am really thankful for your help. Most of the overflow errors have been resolve based on your suggestion. But I am still getting errors from the square root that contain  Pp and Np. I updated k2, r2, q2 and v2 as shown below after defining k1, r1, v1 and q1 first:                                                                                                                   
    k2 = dz*funPs(Ps+k1/2, Pp+r1/2)
    r2 = dz*funPp(Ps+r1/2, Pp+r1/2, Ns+q1/2)  
    q2 = dz*funNs(Ps+q1/2, Pp+q1/2, Ns+q1/2, Np+v1/2)
    v2 = dz*funNp(Ps+v1/2, Pp+v1/2, Np+v1/2)

Comment: The associations of variable and update have to be corrected everywhere, not just in the example I gave. The square root, if it is still a problem,needs to be extended and mollified, for instance using $x/\max(\epsilon,\sqrt{|x|})$

Comment: Hi Lutz, I did updated all the parameters as shown below:k2 = dz*funPs(Ps+k1/2, Pp+r1/2)
    q2 = dz*funNs(Ps+k1/2, Pp+r1/2, Ns+q1/2, Np+v1/2)
    r2 = dz*funPp(Ps+k1/2, Pp+r1/2, Ns+q1/2)
    v2 = dz*funNp(Ps+k1/2, Pp+r1/2, Np+v1/2)
    
    k3 = dz*funPs(Ps+k2/2, Pp+r2/2)
    q3 = dz*funNs(Ps+k2/2, Pp+r2/2, Ns+q2/2, Np+v2/2)
    r3 = dz*funPp(Ps+k2/2, Pp+r2/2, Ns+q2/2)
    v3 = dz*funNp(Ps+k2/2, Pp+r2/2, Np+v2/2)
    
    k4 = dz*funPs(Ps+k3,Pp+r3)
    q4 = dz*funNs(Ps+k3,Pp+r3, Ns+q3, Np+v3)
    r4 = dz*funPp(Ps+k3,Pp+r3, Ns+q3)
    v4 = dz*funNp(Ps+k3,Pp+r3, Np+v3)

Comment: I am still getting this RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  b = (gR/Aeff)*(np.sqrt(2*Pp*Np))*Ps  and b = -(wS/wP)*(gR/Aeff)*(Ps)*np.sqrt(2*Pp*Np), which are the square root that contained Pp and Np. But I have square root that contained Pp only but there was no error. I think the problem might be from multiplying those two parameters. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Don't write your own ODE solver. There are perfectly good libraries (e.g https://pypi.org/project/diffeqpy/)  that use better algorithms (e.g. Tsit5), with adaptive time-stepping and  error control, that will also prevent you from making typos in your ODE solver implimentation.